SQL Procedure that creates a Table
I made a procedure with an input parameter. What the Procedure does is create a table, and I want to pass an  argument as the table's name but it seems I'm doing something wrong. What ended up happening was that the table took the variable name of the parameter instead of the argument.
I looked around the internet for answers, I tried following alternative code syntax from articles and blogposts but none of them have done any favors for me.
//HERE IS THE CODE I MADE BELOW:
 
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE BRONKO(IN cheese VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE cheese(
ID int(15),
Barangay VARCHAR(30),
LastName VARCHAR(30),
FirstName VARCHAR(15),
MiddleName VARCHAR(15),
YY INT(5),
MM INT(2),
DD INT(2),
AGE INT(3),
Gender VARCHAR(10),
Prd_Cvrd_2024 VARCHAR(40),
Amount INT(15)
);

END $$

DELIMITER ;

-------------------------------------------------------//

For instance, I want to create a table, I would have to use this code syntax:
CALL BRONKO('TABLE1'). I expected to have a table that has been named 'TABLE1', but instead
I got a table that has been named 'cheese'.
I even tried to do a bit of 'swizzling' to see if that would work, something like this.... :
CREATE PROCEDURE BRONKO(IN cheese VARCHAR(15))

BEGIN

DECLARE tommy VARCHAR(15);
SET tommy = cheese;
CREATE TABLE tommy(
___________________________________

.....but nothing changed.

Study dynamic SQL (PREPARE statement).

okay, I will do that.
